# Bash - quoted variable expansion mixed with sed yields bad substitution

Tags: bash, sed

I have problem with this sed oneliner

```
sed -i -n "1h; 1!H; ${g; :a s/\(Name=\"$key\".*<\!\[CDATA\[\"\)$val\(\"\]\]>\)/\1$deval\2/;ta p}"
```

Obviously I need to expand variable `key`, `val` and `deval` in sed. So I need the `"` around sed command.

With this command I get

`bash: !H: event not found`

escaping the `!` corrects it

```
sed -i -n "1h; 1\!H; ${g; :a s/\(Name=\"$key\".*<\!\[CDATA\[\"\)$val(\"\]\]>\)/\1$deval\2/;ta p}"
```

With this I get

`bash: sed -i -n "1h; 1\!H; ${g; :a s/\(Name=\"$key\".*<\!\[CDATA\[\"\)$val\(\"\]\]>\)/\1$deval\2/;ta p}" :bad substitution`

So I guess the `{` is a problem. Trying to fix it like this

`sed -i -n "1h; 1\!H; $\{g; :a s/\(Name=\"$key\".*<\!\[CDATA\[\"\)$val(\"\]\]>\)/\1$deval\2/;ta p}"`

yields

`sed: -e expression 1, char 6: unknown command: "\"`

What is going on here? How can I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried single outer quotes? `sed ' ... '`

Comment: Of course... the variables won't expand then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event not found` is only a problem in interactive shells because `histexpand` is enabled by default. If you either run `set +H` first or put it in a script and run it from there, Bash will leave your `!`s alone.

`${..}` is variable substitution syntax (so a mangled value gives `bad substitution`). Let `sed` treat it as a block of commands to do on the final line by escaping the `$`, as in `\${ .. }`.

In full:

```
set +H
key="foo"
val="bar"
deval="puppies"
echo 'Name="foo" <![CDATA["bar"]]>' > file
sed -i -n "1h; 1!H; \${g; :a s/\(Name=\"$key\".*<!\[CDATA\[\"\)$val\(\"\]\]>\)/\1$deval\2/;ta p}" file
cat file
```

Will print `Name="foo" <![CDATA["puppies"]]>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use separate single-quoted strings:

```
sed -i -n '1h; 1!H; ${g; :a s/\(Name='"$key"'.*<\!\[CDATA\[\"\)'"$val"'\(\"\]\]>\)/\1'"$deval"'\2/;ta p}'
```

Comment: Tried on a little example `sed 's/'$key'//'` `sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated 's' command`

Comment: Are you sure you exported the 'key' variable first? E.g: `export key="o"; echo "Hello" | sed 's/'$key'//'`

Comment: Why should I export it? I need it only in script.

Comment: While putting the constant parts of the string in single-quotes is a good idea, you still want to have the variable parts in double-quotes (e.g. `sed 's/'"$key"'//'`) -- otherwise, if your variable values contain whitespace and/or wildcards the shell will interpret them in unwanted ways before they're passed to sed. The "unterminated 's' command" error is exactly what I'd expect if there's whitespace in the value...

Comment: @svante there should absolutely not be any need to export to the environment in the use case given here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy @bartimar sorry - absolutely no need to export. Just make sure you **set** the key variable for a little example to work. If $key is empty you'll get the error message. Updated example: `key="o"; echo "Hello" | sed 's/'"$key"'//'`